# A question concerning Past Perfect continuous

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, perfect-continuous

*He had been drinking milk out the cartoon when mom walked into the kitchen*

I'm reading past perfect continuous in my grammar book and the rule says it is used for an that began before a certain point in the past and continued up to that time.

Does the preceding sentence means the subject denoted by the pronoun *he* was drinking milk out the carton but stopped as soon his mom walked into the kitchen?

Comment: No, it doesn’t mean he stopped. “When” does not so indicate.

Comment: @Michael Harvey yes

Comment: @Xanne so it means he was still drinking milk when mom walked into the kitchen?

Comment: We don't know if he was drinking milk at the moment Mom walked in. All we know for sure is that he had previously been drinking milk.

Comment: We are more likely to drink milk from a *carton* than from a *cartoon*.